# Odd behavior when calling addSubView in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have created a `UIView` in IB and when I add it to my `UIViewController` in `viewDidLoad` the view's background color is changed to `clearColor` and the buttons are not clickable (they do not receive touches). If I try and set the background color in code nothing happens. It looks like this:

[image]

However, if I run the exact same code in `viewWillAppear` it appears normally and is clickable like this:

[image]

The code is this simple and is the only code in `viewDidLoad` (I have stripped out all other code in there to see if that was the issue):

```
[myView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

I have tried calling `bringSubviewToFront` and that did nothing. Any ideas?

Some other things to note:

- the `UIView` is in the same NIB as the view controller's main view and is connected via an `IBOutlet`.
- the NIB file was created separately from the view controller and is
  initialized calling `initWithNibName`.
- I have set the Custom Class and view outlet in the NIB file to match the view controller.
- Autolayout is turned off for the NIB file
- There is no Storyboard

Comment: Thats odd,I use similar codes in 4 of my apps without a problem. my best guess is - you hit a new bug,  a [self.view setneedsDisplay] is required if you want it to work after viewdidload.

Comment: I have used this pattern many times before as well. This is the first time in XCode 5.1 so it has to be a new issue. setNeedsDisplay does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At issue here is we don't know what's up when you add a view in `viewDidLoad`. It's not enough to know that it works in `viewWillAppear`. We have to know it's state when it doesn't appear. Towards that goal, I present:

### Tips for Debugging `UIView` in the Blind

Implementing the following (often in combination) can help diagnose the source of common view problems.

#### Existence

- Set a breakpoint. Did it hit?
- Is the view non-`nil`?
- Is it being added to a superview?
- Is the superview non-nil?
- Does the superview have a `-window`?

#### Visibility

- Is it `-hidden`?
- Does the superview `-clipsToBounds`?
- Make the view bigger. Can you see it now?
- Make it a *lot* bigger. How about now?
- Set its center to the superview's center.
- Make it bright green.
- Make sure `-alpha` is 1-ish.

#### Hierarchy

- Is the view a subclass? Does a stock `UIView` work instead?
- Are any view classes extended with categories?
- Do any view controller lifecycle methods (`viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, etc) mess with the view?
- Does your view controller call `super` everyplace it should (`viewDidLoad`, etc)?

#### Containment

- Is your view controller contained by another view controller that draws on top of it (for example, `UINavigationController`, `UITabBarController`, etc)?
- Does your view controller `-wantsFullscreenLayout`?
- Are there edges in `-edgesForExtendedLayout`?
- Can you try rendering your view controller by itself outside of containment?

#### Autolayout

- Are you getting any constraint consistency errors in log/term?
- Have you set a width/height (or an intrinsic size)?
- Is `-translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set appropriately?

#### Xcode

- Have you cleaned your project and rebuilt?
- Have you "Reset Content and Settings…" in the simulator?
- Have you tried on both simulator and a device?
- Have you quit Xcode and started it again?
- Have you shutdown your computer and started again?
- Are you on a beta? Stop that.

#### Minimum Viable Reproduction

- If you create a fresh project with a fresh view and view controller, does the problem persist?
- If you copy and paste your nibs/storyboards?
- If you copy and paste your classes?

I'll add more as they come to me.

Comment: Epic. I'll run through these when I have some time and let you know.

Comment: Well I reproduced it in a minimum viable reproduction with a single viewcontroller. And found that if I removed the auto-sizing constraints it fixed it. BUT, that doesn't explain why the buttons on the view were positioned in the right spot and not receiving touches, or why the background changed to clear and could not be changed in code.

Answer (score 4):

Not enough info here to know for sure, but my guess is your controller is set to extend views behind top bars. I don't believe autolayout things like `topLayoutGuide`, etc. get computed until after `viewDidLoad`.

Possible solutions:

- Uncheck the "Extend Edges Under Top Bars" box on your view controller if you don't need that.
- Add the view in `viewDidLoad` but position it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`
- Position `myView` with autolayout constraints instead of explicitly setting its frame.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I should note Autolayout is turned off for this NIB. Where is "Extend Edges Under Top Bars"?

Comment: Ah, if you're using a nib, it won't be there. It's a property you set on view controllers in storyboard. Same advice applies, though. If somethign is working in `viewWillAppear` and not in `viewDidLoad` it's usually because of a layout issue. Try doing layout-ish things in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead.

Comment: I don't use Storyboard. I have a workaround using `ViewWillAppear` but I want to understand why this is not working. I have done this many times before.

Comment: First, remember `viewWillAppear` might not be appropriate as it gets called every time a view is *shown* (as opposed to every time it's *created*, like `viewDidLoad`). Secondly, as I've said, I think this is caused by layout that happens after `viewDidLoad` but before `viewWillAppear` which changes frame of your view. You don't give enough information for me to know this for sure, but if moving layout to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` fixes it, then that's a pretty good indicator that's the issue.

Comment: Moving it there does fix it. I've always laid out my subviews on `viewDidLoad` so I'm not sure why this no longer works and have seen no documentation on it. I still don't understand why this is happening now. But I appreciate the fix.

Comment: I should also note when I add and position other subviews programmatically in the same `viewDidLoad` they work fine (e.g. UICollectionView). It's only this one view that comes from a NIB it doesn't like.

Comment: BTW, if I add the view in `viewDidLoad` and then position it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` it doesn't work. I have to add it and position it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` for it to work.